# libgdx controller axis rounds up to 1 or -1

Tags: java, controller, libgdx

When using a xbox controller in libgdx the value of the stick axis in the ControllerListener rounds up to 1 or -1 when is near that position both vertically and horizontally whick makes it seems not smooth. 
Is this the normal behaviour? 
Is there a way to make it uniform through all values?

Comment: Did you look at the raw values in the OS? Perhaps the OS is responsible for the rounding rather than LibGDX?

Comment: I've just checked it, it was the the os as you suggested. Thank you :)